# OpenCV cv::Circle comes out gray on iPhone UI

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opencv

Currently I am using OpenCV to process images from an AVCaptureSession. The app right now takes these images and draws cv::Circles on the blobs. The tracking is working but when I draw the circle, it comes out as this gray, distorted circle when it should be green. Is it that OpenCV drawing functions don't work properly with iOS apps? Or is there something I can do to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a screen shot: (Ignore that giant green circle on the bottom)
[image]

The cv::Circle is around the outside of the black circle.

Here is where I converted the CMSampleBuffer into a cv::Mat:

```
enter code here CVImageBufferRef pixelBuff = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

cv::Mat cvMat;

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuff, 0);

int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuff);
int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuff);
unsigned char *pixel = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuff);

cvMat = cv::Mat(bufferHeight, bufferWidth, CV_8UC4, pixel);

cv::Mat grayMat;

cv::cvtColor(cvMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);


CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuff, 0);
```

This is the cv::Circle command:

```
if (keypoints.size() > 0) {
    cv::Point p(keypoints[0].pt.x, keypoints[0].pt.y);
    printf("x: %f, y: %f\n",keypoints[0].pt.x, keypoints[0].pt.y);
    cv::circle(cvMat, p, keypoints[0].size/2, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0);
}
```

Keypoints is the vector of blobs that have been detected.

Comment: How thick is the circle that you are drawing? It looks like there is a problem with the way the pixels are accessed. It will be nice to see the code that you use to convert the image to cv::Mat and vice versa

Comment: Okay I'll edit it now. Basically what I do is convert the CMSampleBuffer to the cvMat. Also the thickness is 2.